# Using GeoComplete with RequireJS (with shim config)

Tags: javascript, require.js

I am using the GeoComplete plugin with RequireJS
It works, but please could someone confirm I've done this correctly, mainly my understanding of shim:

```
    requirejs.config({
        waitSeconds: 120,
        paths: {
            async: './lib/async',
            jquery: './lib/jquery-1.7.2.min',
            geocomplete: './lib/jquery.geocomplete.min'
        },
        shim: {
            'geocomplete': ['jquery'],
        }
    });

    require(['async!http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false', 'jquery', 'geocomplete'], function () {
        $("#geocomplete").geocomplete({
            map: "#map_canvas"
        });
    }
    );
```

The way I understand shim, is, GeoComplete doesn't support AMD, but has a dependency on jQuery, so my set up basically says "load geocomplete **after** jquery"

Is that correct?

Comment: Does it work as you expected? If it does, you have probably done it correctly :)

Comment: haha, yes, it does.... was just very new to requirejs, and hadn't quite got my head around the idea of the shim. Think I get it now!

Answer (score 5):

The only thing that I see looking at this code is that you didn't keep a fully consistent formatting, and I at first thought you had an extra set of brackets or parentheses.

[image]

You should do it like the `});` farther above in the code.

Keep everything consistent, you probably already know this though.

Comment: I agree, and I usually have code-ocd when it comes to this!